# TypeError: Connot read property 'render' of undefiend while testing a js on node js using mocha and chai

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, chai

I am doing some testing on my js function and it is my first time doing this and I am getting an error of:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined

I am using chai and mocha. Here is my test code

test1.test.js

```
it('should return all the data based on the given  appname' , function () {
   assert.isArray(acc.fetchData().getKeys());
})
```

This is what on my js function:

```
exports.fetchData = function (req, res) {
'use strict';

  res.render('pages/test1', {
    test: a.getKeys(),
    arrayToPull: rootValueCombination
  });
};
```

I tried using supertest but I have no luck. I used istanbul as a code coverage which is a bit odd as i am getting 100% but I am getting failed on mocha test.

Answer (score 0):

You are not passing a parameter to `fetchData`

```
assert.isArray(acc.fetchData().getKeys());
```

and `res` is the second parameter of the `function`. You need to pass the correct variable to the `function`, the one which has a `render` `function`.